# In Excel my formula is skipping the first two cells of a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

Hi I have an Excel Spreadsheet and I'm trying to convert a table with multiple rows and columns into just one column for sorting and filtering. But the issue is that it doesn't start at cell A2 where it's supposed to start, it starts at A2 of column C so it starts at the third letter, letter 'b' and skips the first two letters 'g' and 't'. Does anyone see an issue with the formula that's causing this?

Formula: `=INDEX($A$2:$C$11, ROUNDUP(ROWS(G$2:G8)/3,0), MOD(ROWS(G$2:G8)-1,3)+1)`

Screenshot:

[image: excel spreadsheet screenshot]

Comment: If you already have the row & column values you want in column H & I, why not reference those directly? `=INDEX($A$2:$C$11,H2,I2)` If that doesn't exist in your original data, it would make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this without the benefit of helper columns, then in cell `G2` adjust your formula to:

`=INDEX($A$2:$C$11,ROUNDUP(ROWS(G$2:G2)/3,0),1+MOD(ROWS(G$2:G2)-1,3))`

and copy this down the remaining cells in column `G`.

The formula in your screenshot uses `ROWS(G$2:G4)` (not `ROWS(G$2:G8)` as specified in your question!!). You were almost there - just change the two instances of `ROWS(G$2:G4)` in your formula to `ROWS(G$2:G2)`